# draggable flat-list is only working on mobile, i am looking for a similar implementation in react native windows

Tags: react-native-windows

Need to create a list with re ordering of items in react native windows.

draggable flat-list is only working on mobile, i am looking for a similar implementation in windows.
Need to re order the string of items . items are in a list of strings.